# Why is my navigation controller's animation type changing?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a starting screen for an app that has a login button and a sign in button.

it's embedded in a navigation controller so that I can push the login/sign in screens as needed.

When the app first loads up, the navigation controller works normally - it has the top bar and when I push a new VC it slides in from the side,**However**, once the user logs in and then logs back out, the animation changes to one where it slides up from the bottom of the screen and there is no navigation bar.

How would I set the navigation controller's style back to normal?

**logout function:**

```
@IBAction func handleLogOut(_ sender: Any) {
        self.userDefault.set(false, forKey: "usersignedin")
        self.userDefault.synchronize()

        self.center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()



        let startingViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.startingViewController) as? StartingViewController
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = startingViewController
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }
```

Comment: If you are embedding your `StartingViewController` in a `UINavigationController` in the storyboard and that's the initial one, why not`let startingViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.startingViewController) as? StartingViewController` => let navigationController = self.storyboards?.instantiateInitialViewController(); self.view.window?.rootVC = navigationController`?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. If you want, post your solution as an answer so I can mark it right

Comment: Why not just `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController()`? you will be able to reuse the existing controller and the animation transition would be backward..

Comment: That would work if it was still within the same navigation controller, but after the user logs in I change the rootviewcontroller to another one